# fs.readDirSync doesn't return the files in a folder

Tags: node.js, file, async-await, filesystems, node.js-fs

I have this small class that consists of a few methods.

```
export class imageHandler {
  id: string;
  imageFolder: string;
  jobFolder: string;
  bucket: Bucket;

  constructor(id: string, imageFolder: string) {
    this.id = id;
    this.imageFolder = imageFolder;
    this.bucket = new Bucket();

    //Creates the Job Directory and stores it in the variable.
    fs.mkdirSync(`${imageFolder}/${id}`, { recursive: true });
    this.jobFolder = `${imageFolder}/${id}`;
  }

  async saveImages(urls: string[]) {
    await getImages(urls, this.jobFolder)
  }

  async uploadImages() {
    const images = fs.readdirSync(this.jobFolder);
    console.log("These are the Images: ", images);
    console.log("This is the Job Folder", this.jobFolder);
  }
}
```

The `saveImages()` method calls upon `getImages()` Function which downloads the Images from the List and saves them in the `jobFolder` directory.
Once the images have finished downloading, I want to call the `uploadImages()` method, Which will take the files from the `jobFolder` and upload them to a `S3` bucket.
But, `FS.readDirSync()` can't find any images in the folder. And returns an empty `Array`.
Here's my `Main` function.

```
const main = async (url: string) => {
  const id = uid(5);
  const IH = new imageHandler(id, imageFolder);

  await IH.saveImages(data?.images).then((val) => {
    IH.uploadImages();
  });
};
```

I know the Images are being downloaded and saved as I can see the Images. But my program can't see them while running. What can I do to fix this?
Here's my `getImages()` function .

```
export const getImages = async (
  links: string[],
  folder: string,
  extra?: string
) => {
  links.forEach(async (link, i) => {
    const fileLocation = path.resolve(
      folder,
      extra ? extra : "",
      `image${i}.jpeg`
    );

    await axios({
      method: "get",
      url: extractImageUrl(link),
      responseType: "stream",
    }).then(function (response) {
      response.data
        .pipe(new ExifTransformer())
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileLocation));
    });
  });
};
```

Can anyone help me figure out the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getImages()` function returns a promise, but that promise is not connected to when the asynchronous operations in your function are actually complete.  Thus, the code following this call is trying to read the directory before the files have been written.  This is for two reasons:

1. `.forEach()` is not asynchronous-aware and does not wait for the `await` in its callback.
2. `.pipe()` is non-blocking and thus your `async` function has no awareness at all for when it is complete or if it had an error.

First, remove all use of `.forEach()` in asynchronous code.  It is not promise aware and does NOT wait for the `await` in it's callback function.  Instead, replace it with a regular `for` loop.

Then, wrap a promise around your `.pipe()` operation so you are watching for both completion and errors.

And, don't mix `await` and `.then()` as that makes for far less readable code.

```
export const getImages = async (
    links: string[],
    folder: string,
    extra?: string
) => {
    for (const [i: number, link: string] of links.entries()) {
        const fileLocation = path.resolve(
            folder,
            extra ? extra : "",
            `image${i}.jpeg`
        );

        const response = await axios({
            method: "get",
            url: extractImageUrl(link),
            responseType: "stream",
        });
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            response.data
                .pipe(new ExifTransformer())
                .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileLocation))
                .on("error", reject)
                .on("finish", resolve);
        });
    }
};
```

Or, you can simplify a bit by using the promise version of `pipeline()`:

```
import { pipeline } from 'node:stream/promises';

export const getImages = async (
    links: string[],
    folder: string,
    extra?: string
) => {
    for (const [i: number, link: string] of links.entries()) {
        const fileLocation = path.resolve(
            folder,
            extra ? extra : "",
            `image${i}.jpeg`
        );

        const response = await axios({
            method: "get",
            url: extractImageUrl(link),
            responseType: "stream",
        });
        await pipeline(response.data, new ExifTransformer(), fs.createWriteStream(fileLocation));
    }
}
```

Note, this is the simpler implementation that sequences each of the images and writes.  It's possible to write a more parallel implementation that still notifies when everything is complete, but allows multiple reads/writes to operate in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This instantly solved my Problem. And literally made my code work better than it was working. Also fixed a couple of other bugs I was facing. I wasn't aware that there was a async pipeline. Thank you for helping me with this. You're great.